# Subida de archivos en php

Tags: php, upload

Voy directo al grano a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.
Quiero permitir a los usuarios de mi web subir archivos y he creado esto.

```html
<form action="/contenidos/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileupform">
  <!--Subida de Archivos-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="archivos">Subida de archivos</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="fileup" id="fileup" accept=".doc, .docx, .ppt,.pptx, .pdf">
      </div>
</form>
```

Ahora bien, no tengo ni idea de qué codigo poner en uploads.php para que funcione todo correctamente y los archivos subidos vayan a /contenidos/uploads

Hago un edit para enseñar el código que tengo creado en php para upload.php

```html
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Y ya está
Muchas gracias,

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], así sabrás cómo funciona el sitio y de paso ganarás tu primera medalla! Tu pregunta es muy amplia e incluso puede basarse en opiniones. Te recomiendo que intentes por tu cuenta crear el método que reciba el archivo en tu servidor y cuando tengas dificultades, las expones aquí con el detalle necesario para poder darte una mano. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La transferencia de archivos se realiza "exactamente igual" que con otros datos, sólo que en lugar de recibir los datos a través del array $_POST o $_GET los recibes a través del array $_FILES, así:

```
$_FILES['fileup']
```

También puedes acceder a otros datos del fichero enviado, por ejemplo:

```
$_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'];
$_FILES['fileup']['name'];
$_FILES['fileup']['size'];
$_FILES['fileup']['type'];
$_FILES['fileup']['error']
```